# MySQL suddenly stopped to work - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)

Tags: mysql, debian

My website outputs the following error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
```

I tried many solutions I found online, none of them worked.

```
# service mysql status

Nov 08 07:51:00 vps412690.ovh.net mysql[14525]: /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full...iled!
Nov 08 07:51:00 vps412690.ovh.net /etc/init.d/mysql[14544]: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!
Nov 08 07:51:00 vps412690.ovh.net systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 08 07:51:00 vps412690.ovh.net systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Nov 08 07:51:00 vps412690.ovh.net systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
Nov 08 07:57:48 vps412690.ovh.net systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
```

I tried to move the contents in `/var/lib/mysql` to `user/lib/mysql` - I still get this error.

OS: Debian 8 (Jessie) (64-bit version)

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

shows different PID every time I run it!

What else I'm missing?

UPDATE:

My `sda1` partition is full

```
/dev/sda1        20G   19G  156M 100% /
```

clean didn't fix it, what else I can do?

Answer (score 3):

The error message you've copied into your post tells you what the issue is:

> ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!

You don't have enough space on the partition. You need to either extend the partition or delete stuff from it so that there will be enough space for the database.